# convert text to time stamp in postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have data extracted from a website as the image
[data]

[image: 1]

I need to convert it as timestamp date and time
how can I do that

Comment: Simply cast it, `"date string"::timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

The text timestamps are already in a format which should be directly castable, e.g.

```
SELECT '2021-07-06T12:32:00'::timestamp;
```

### Demo

Comment: Go  a further! Store the data with the proper data type (timestamp or timestamptz). Make the indicated conversion as you store the data. Then it is available for any necessary date/time operation needed without the conversion task on use.